# Local Notification gets fired even when remove app from simulator

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator, ios10, nsusernotification

i am implementing UserNotification in an app, Now the thing is that once i set a notification with repeat of every minute, it works fine. Once i remove app from simulator and install again, the old set notification keeps on striking.Don't it get removed if i remove app from simulator? Any help !!

Comment: What kind of notification do you implement?

Comment: No they don't. Just make sure you remove all pending notifications on first run.

Comment: [centerNotification removeAllPendingNotificationRequests];  here is the code i use to cancel notification.

Comment: @Andy  hey you are right, these are no pending notification, it is already notified but it is on  repeat mode, repeating after every hour

Answer (score 0):

Notifications may be scheduled for some time even after you remove and reinstall the app. Make sure that you cancel all scheduled notifications on the first run of your application.

You can use `NSUserDefaults` or on-disk storage to store a flag to find when your app runs in the very first time.

Comment: tried to remove all pending as well delivered(those which are on repeat mode) notification

Comment: if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"bIsFirstLaunch"]){
      
        if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 10.0){
        
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
            
        }else{
        
            [centerNotification removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
            [centerNotification removeAllPendingNotificationRequests];
    }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"bIsFirstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}